# Apache cxf Jax-RS 2.0 interceptors

Tags: java, validation, cxf, jax-rs, interceptor

I am facing an error while parsing. I am not able to understand how to resolve it.

The exception is

```
####<Dec 3, 2014 3:06:25 AM EST> <Notice> <StdErr> <55NWBS1> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1417593985449> <BEA-000000> <Dec 3, 2014 3:06:25 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://service.automatedbluesheets.clearsum.mks.iis.korra.org/}Version has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.ValidationUtils.getResourceInstance(ValidationUtils.java:39)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.JAXRSBeanValidationOutInterceptor.getServiceObject(JAXRSBeanValidationOutInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.apache.cxf.validation.AbstractValidationInterceptor.handleMessage(AbstractValidationInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:197)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:149)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:290)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPut(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:226)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:730)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)>
```

cxf beans configuration file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

        <beans:import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

        <context:property-placeholder />
        <context:annotation-config />

        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" />
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PreferencesPlaceholderConfigurer" />


        <jee:jndi-lookup id="insiderManagerFacadeEJB"
            jndi-name="InsiderManagerFacade#com.nyse.mks.iis.InsiderManager.domain.facade.session.InsiderManagerFacade"
            expected-type="com.nyse.mks.iis.InsiderManager.domain.facade.session.InsiderManagerFacade" />

        <jee:jndi-lookup id="blueSheetFacadeEJB"
            jndi-name="RequestBluesheetFacade#com.nyse.mks.iis.requestbluesheet.facade.RequestBluesheetFacade"
            expected-type="com.nyse.mks.iis.requestbluesheet.facade.RequestBluesheetFacade" />

        <jee:jndi-lookup id="bsFacadeEJB"
            jndi-name="BSFacade#com.nyse.mks.iis.requestbluesheet.facade.BSFacade"
            expected-type="com.nyse.mks.iis.requestbluesheet.facade.BSFacade" />

        <beans:bean id="bluesheetRequestFacade"
            class="org.korra.iis.mks.clearsum.bluesheets.BluesheetRequestFacadeOfClearsumImpl">
            <beans:property name="blueSheetFacade" ref="blueSheetFacadeEJB" />
            <beans:property name="insiderManagerFacade" ref="insiderManagerFacadeEJB" />
            <beans:property name="bsFacade" ref="bsFacadeEJB" />
        </beans:bean>

    <!--    <beans:bean id="marketParticipantDao" class="com.nyse.mks.iis.requestbluesheet.daoimpl.bluesheet.MarketParticipantDAO" /> -->


        <beans:bean id="jsonProvider"
            class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" >
        </beans:bean>

    <!--    <beans:bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
           <beans:property name="schemaHandler" ref="schemaHolder"/>
        </beans:bean> -->

    <!--    <beans:bean id="schemaHolder" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.schemas.SchemaHandler"> -->
    <!--       <beans:property name="schemas" ref="theSchemas"/> -->
    <!--    </beans:bean> -->

    <!--    <util:list id="theSchemas"> -->
    <!--      <beans:value><![CDATA[classpath:/META-INF/schemas/AutomatedBluesheets_V1.xsd]]></beans:value> -->
    <!--    </util:list>    -->

        <beans:bean id="versionBean"
            class="org.korra.iis.mks.clearsum.automatedbluesheets.service.Version">
            <beans:property name="automatedBluesheet" ref="automatedBluesheet" />
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean id="automatedBluesheet"
            class="org.korra.iis.mks.clearsum.automatedbluesheets.service.AutomatedBluesheet">
            <beans:property name="bluesheetRequestFacade" ref="bluesheetRequestFacade" />
        </beans:bean>

        <!-- <jee:local-slsb id="myComponent" jndi-name="InsiderManagerFacade#com.nyse.mks.iis.InsiderManager.domain.facade.session.InsiderManagerFacade" 
            business-interface="com.nyse.mks.iis.InsiderManager.domain.facade.session.InsiderManagerFacade"/> -->

        <beans:bean id="exceptionMapper" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.ValidationExceptionMapper" />
        <beans:bean id="validationProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationProvider" />

        <beans:bean id="validationInInterceptor"
                class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.JAXRSBeanValidationInInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="provider" ref="validationProvider" />
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="validationOutInterceptor"
                class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.JAXRSBeanValidationOutInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="provider" ref="validationProvider" />
        </beans:bean>


        <!-- <bean class="org.apache.cxf.management.web.logging.atom.AtomPushBean" 
            init-method="init"> -->
        <!-- <property name="url" value="http://localhost:8080/automatedbluesheets-1.0-SNAPSHOT/"/> -->
        <!-- <property name="level" value="ALL" /> -->
        <!-- </bean> -->


        <jaxrs:server id="services" address="/">
            <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
                <beans:ref bean="versionBean" />
                <beans:ref bean="automatedBluesheet" />
            </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

            <jaxrs:providers>
                <beans:ref bean="exceptionMapper"/>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonProvider" />
            </jaxrs:providers>

            <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            </jaxrs:extensionMappings>

            <jaxrs:languageMappings>
                <entry key="en" value="en-gb" />
            </jaxrs:languageMappings>

    <!--        <jaxrs:features> -->
    <!--             <cxf:logging/> -->
    <!--        </jaxrs:features> -->

            <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
                <ref bean="validationInInterceptor" />
            </jaxrs:inInterceptors>

            <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
                <ref bean="validationOutInterceptor" />
            </jaxrs:outInterceptors> 

              <jaxrs:schemaLocations>
                 <jaxrs:schemaLocation><![CDATA[classpath:META-INF/schemas/AutomatedBluesheets_V1.xsd]]></jaxrs:schemaLocation>
                 <!-- Possible from CXF 3.0.0 milestone2: -->
                 <!-- 
                 <jaxrs:schemaLocation>classpath:/META-INF/schemas/</jaxrs:schemaLocation>
                 --> 
              </jaxrs:schemaLocations>

        </jaxrs:server>

    </beans:beans>
```

Rest service java classes are:
        /**
         * Created by Apache CXF WadlToJava code generator
         **/
        package org.korra.iis.mks.clearsum.automatedbluesheets.service;

```
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    import org.korra.iis.mks.clearsum.automatedbluesheets.schema.AutomatedBluesheetRequestInput;
    import org.korra.iis.mks.clearsum.automatedbluesheets.schema.AutomatedBluesheetResponse;
    import org.korra.iis.mks.clearsum.bluesheets.BluesheetRequestFacadeOfClearsum;

    public class AutomatedBluesheet {

        /**
         * This is variable to hold the bluesheetRequestFacade
         */
        private BluesheetRequestFacadeOfClearsum bluesheetRequestFacade;

        /**
         * @return the bluesheetRequestFacade
         */
        public BluesheetRequestFacadeOfClearsum getBluesheetRequestFacade() {
            return bluesheetRequestFacade;
        }

        /**
         * @param bluesheetRequestFacade
         *            the bluesheetRequestFacade to set
         */
        public void setBluesheetRequestFacade(
                BluesheetRequestFacadeOfClearsum bluesheetRequestFacade) {
            this.bluesheetRequestFacade = bluesheetRequestFacade;
        }

        @PUT
        @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
        @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
        public AutomatedBluesheetResponse createRequest(
                AutomatedBluesheetRequestInput automatedBluesheetRequest)
                throws WebApplicationException {

            AutomatedBluesheetResponse automatedBluesheetResponse = null;
            try {
                automatedBluesheetResponse = bluesheetRequestFacade
                        .instateBlueSheet(automatedBluesheetRequest);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                throw new WebApplicationException(e);
            }
            return automatedBluesheetResponse;
        }

    }
```

Class 2:
        /**
         * Created by Apache CXF WadlToJava code generator
        **/
        package org.korra.iis.mks.clearsum.automatedbluesheets.service;

```
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;

    @Path("/v1")
    public class Version {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private AutomatedBluesheet automatedBluesheet;

        /**
         * @param automatedBluesheet the automatedBluesheet to set
         */
        public void setAutomatedBluesheet(AutomatedBluesheet automatedBluesheet) {
            this.automatedBluesheet = automatedBluesheet;
        }

        @Path("/automatedBluesheet")
        public AutomatedBluesheet getAutomatedBluesheet() {
        return automatedBluesheet;
        }

    }
```

POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.korra.mks.iis.clearsum</groupId>
    <artifactId>RequestBluesheetWEB</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <jackson.version>1.8.6</jackson.version>
        <cxf.version>3.0.2</cxf.version>
        <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jaxb2.version>2.1.0</jaxb2.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>5.1.3.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
        <javax.el.version>2.2.4</javax.el.version>
        <jettison.version>1.3</jettison.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <finalName>RequestBluesheetWEB</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/jasperreports</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</warSourceExcludes>
                    <webXml>WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.korra.mks.iis.clearsum</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>Client</artifactId>
                                    <version>${pom.version}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
                                    <excludes>**/org/**</excludes>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}/WEB-INF/classes/reports</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                        <version>3.7.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.15</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <logLevel>ALL</logLevel>
                            <module>org.korra.clearsum.Clearsum</module>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}</output>
                            <style>PRETTY</style>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>WebContent/META-INF/schemas</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaFiles>*.xsd</schemaFiles>
                            <packageName>org.korra.iis.mks.clearsum.automatedbluesheets.schema</packageName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.korra.mks.iis.clearsum</groupId>
            <artifactId>I2RequestBluesheetCommon</artifactId>
            <version>${pom.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.korra.mks.iis.clearsum</groupId>
            <artifactId>I2RequestBluesheetDAL</artifactId>
            <version>${pom.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.korra.mks.iis.clearsum</groupId>
                    <artifactId>I2RequestBluesheetCommon</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.korra.mks.iis.clearsum</groupId>
            <artifactId>RequestBluesheetEJB</artifactId>
            <version>${pom.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.korra.mks.iis.wsstub</groupId>
                    <artifactId>LGSWSDelegate</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.korra.mks.iis.clearsum</groupId>
                    <artifactId>I2RequestBluesheetCommon</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.korra.mks.iis.clearsum</groupId>
            <artifactId>Client</artifactId>
            <version>${pom.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.korra.mks.iis.commonutility2</groupId>
            <artifactId>IISCommonUtility2</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- <exclusion> <groupId>log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j</artifactId> 
                    </exclusion> -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>castor-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>castor-xml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.korra.mks.iis.insiderManager</groupId>
            <artifactId>InsiderManagerEJB</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.korra.mks.iis.insiderManager</groupId>
            <artifactId>InsiderManagerDAL</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.extjs</groupId>
            <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.8-beta5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.8-beta5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.8-beta5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
            <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>commons-collections</groupId> <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId> 
            <version>3.2.1</version> </dependency> -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.korra.mks.iis.wsstub</groupId>
            <artifactId>StarWSClient</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Rest service dependent jars start  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>${jettison.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
           <version>3.0-b02</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
           <version>3.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
           <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
           <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Rest service dependence ends -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a bug with [CXF `JAXRSBeanValidationFeature`](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/validationfeature.html#ValidationFeature-BeanValidation1.1andJAX-RS2.0) working with [sub-resources](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2416) as in example above.

I've filed a bug report: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6297. Please vote up.

[Sergey Beryozkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1133928/sergey-beryozkin) (CXF JAX-RS lead) is actually very responsive, huge respect! So there is a big chance we'll see this in next release (or at least explained and advised on how to use it properly =) ).

Comment: This is fixed and scheduled for CXF 3.1.0/3.0.5